# Why my question is put on hold?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, homework-and-exercises

I've posted one question here [Please guide me. This question is related to electrical self energy from electrostatic](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/331646/155381) but it was put on hold because it was a homework question. So I edited it following the same rules for editing questions as suggested but it is still on hold! 
Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

First, as of now, zero people [have so far reviewed](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/174182) your edited question.  It's not even been an hour. Patience.

Second, and more importantly: even in its present form (v3), your question is much more like "solve this problem for me" than like the type of conceptual homework-like questions we accept here. It's not clear whether you are having a mathematical question about relating the distance from a source charge with the radius of a sphere, or whether you are confused about the concept of electrical self-energy, or whether you are confused about the difference between a volume charge and a surface charge.  Without knowing what your conceptual stumbling block is, the odds aren't good that an answerer would be able to guide you to a solution.  In that case, it'd be appropriate for the question to remain closed.

Try re-reading the [homework guidelines](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/44126) and reading some other questions on electrostatic self-energy to see the kinds of changes that would make your question answerable here. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: As you suggested, I've edited my question. Is that edit correct?

Comment: In v4, you've change the title, but not the substance of the question. I won't be able to respond to every edit; you'll have to read around and get a feeling for the site. If you are in a hurry, this may not be the place for you --- we are *not* a homework help site.